# Julia DiffResults examples?

Tags: julia

Julia's `ForwardDiff` documentation suggests that computing the function value, gradient and Hessian can be computed in one fell swoop using the `DiffResults` API, but there are NO examples. The `DiffResults` package itself has no examples either, and no documentation to speak of. The use case for this is self-evident: suppose I have a function `f` of a vector argument `x`, and I want to minimize it using Newton's method. Below is the blunt approach, where things get recomputed three times - how would I write it with `DiffResults`?

```
function NewtMin(f, x0, eps)
    fgrad = x-> ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x)
    fhess = x-> ForwardDiff.hessian(f, x)
    oldval = f(x0)
    newx = x0 - fhess(x0)\fgrad(x0)
    newval = f(newx)
    while abs(newval - oldval) > eps
        oldval = newval
        newx = newx - fhess(newx)\fgrad(newx)
        newval = f(newx)
    end
    return newx
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples in the `DiffResults.jl` documentation from http://www.juliadiff.org/DiffResults.jl/stable/.

And this is a simple rewriting of `Newtmin` using `DiffResults`, it works in julia v0.6.4. But I guess it can be refactored and optimized to be more elegant and performant.

```
using ForwardDiff
using DiffResults

function NewtMin(f, x0, eps)
    result = DiffResults.HessianResult(x0)
    ForwardDiff.hessian!(result, f, x0)
    fhess_x0 = DiffResults.hessian(result)
    fgrad_x0 = DiffResults.gradient(result)
    oldval = DiffResults.value(result)
    newx = x0 - fhess_x0\fgrad_x0
    newval = f(newx)
    while abs(newval - oldval) > eps
        oldval = newval
        ForwardDiff.hessian!(result, f, newx)
        fhess_newx = DiffResults.hessian(result)
        fgrad_newx = DiffResults.gradient(result)
        newx = newx - fhess_newx\fgrad_newx
        newval = f(newx)
    end
    return newx
end

foo(x) = sum(x.^2)

NewtMin(foo, [1.,1.,1.], 0.01) 
## which should give a correct result at [0., 0., 0.]
```